# Scala recursive api call

Tags: scala, api, scala-collections

```
val identifiers = List("id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id5","id7","id8","id9","id10")
```

There are 10 ids are there in the list, I need to get all the ids information using some API call either it can be a post or get method.

But here the challenge is the API which returns the id's information won't return a result if the ids are more than 3.

So I want to make an API call for all those IDs in the batch format. the batch size max is 3. Since API won't return results if the ids are more than 3.

Is there any way to achieve to make an API call in a batch of size 3?

**Sample API in curl**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://test/search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "request": {
        "filters": {
           "identifier": ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Do you mean ID1 and ID2, then ID3 and ID4 and the last one is just ID5?

Comment: Yes, It's depending upon the size, if i give size = 1 then it will make api call for every id's

Comment: Can we do using features or await something live recursive format ?

Comment: It's still nor really clear what you want to achieve. Can you please review your question and add a method that represents your API call? So it's possible to see what are the input parameters and what is return value.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Does my answer cover it? Are you interested in how to do the http call too?

Comment: Yes, please Intrested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grouped` to do the grouping by 2 or 3 (whatever you need) elements.

The following code shows how to group, call a method that returns a Future and receive all responses back in the form of a List.

```scala
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

//Emulate a call that returns a Future
def apiCall(ids: List[String]): Future[String] = Future(ids.mkString("[", ",", "]"))

val ids       = List("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5")
val subIds    = ids.grouped(2).toList
//val responses = Future.sequence(subIds.map(apiCall))
val responses = Future.traverse(subIds)(apiCall)
val all       = Await.result(responses, 2.seconds)
println(all)
```

This prints

```
List([ID1,ID2], [ID3,ID4], [ID5])
```

You can do a http request with variety of libraries but the simplest one (in my opinion) is [scalaj-http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http).

The method apiCall can be implemented as following

```scala
def apiCall(ids: List[String]) = Future {
  import scalaj.http.Http
  val idsAsJsonArray = ids.map(id => "\"" + id + "\"").mkString("[", ",", "]")
  Http("https://test/search")
    .postData(s"""
      |{
      |    "request": {
      |        "filters": {
      |           "identifier": $idsAsJsonArray
      |        }
      |    }
      |}
      |""".stripMargin)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .asString
    .body
}
```

Comment: `apiCall` method also should return future ?

Comment: @Manju It may not. It depends if you want to have your http calls to be executed simultaneously or sequentially.

Comment: Await.result(responses, 2.seconds) will it wait until all the response to return?

Comment: @Tulasi yes, till all futures complete with a value. If one of them takes longer than 2 seconds, there will be a timeout exception